# Browser-Sidebar for number conversion?

Tags: opera

does anyone know a sidebar (or 'panel' like it's called in opera) that I can use for number conversions (decimal to hex and so on)? Currently I'm using [this one](http://www.parkenet.com/apl/HexDecConverter.html) but it's a bit too large to fit a narrow sidebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's just a bit of JavaScript, one can roll it oneself:

```
<html>
<body>
  <form>
    <input name="dec" id="dec"
       placeholder="decimal"
       onBlur="document.getElementById('hex').value=
           parseInt(this.value,10).toString(16)"
       ></input>
    <br />
    <input name="hex" id="hex"
       placeholder="hex"
       onBlur="document.getElementById('dec').value=
           parseInt(this.value,16).toString(10)"
       ></input>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```